# Make FB Like button take user to FB page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When clicking the Facebook Like button on my site I want the user's browser to be taken to my Facebook page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible.

If you use the Javascript SDK to subscribe to facebook events http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

then you subscribe to the edge.create event and then fire some js to do this:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        window.location = "http://facebook.com/mypage";
    }
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is all new, shiny, exciting and to be honest, a bit voodoo to me, but it sounds like a good pointer for getting started. I may need to come back to iron out details... Many thanks.

Comment: Mike if you need a complete demo just ask and I can sort one for you.